# C# - wrong string to single conversion

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

I am writing a program to get data from microcontroller to PC. The data is in float format. I tried to convert the string into float using `Convert.ToSingle(string)`, but the conversion result is wrong:

1. "0.11" is converted to 11, sometimes 12.
2. "0.10" is converted to 10. etc

As you can see, it is losing the leading 0. , which is unexpected. How could this happen?

Comment: Try checking your regional settings. I assume that the system on which the conversion does not work has a different decimal separator (probably comma) set.

Comment: Check the duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is culture specific. In some cultures float numbers are separated by a `,` and in some they are separated by a `.`

In your case

```
String a = "0,11";
Convert.ToSingle(a)
```

should result in your desired outcome of 0,11.

So you should explicitly specify a relevant culture that uses `.` as decimal separator. One possibility is the invariant culture which is based on the English language.

Try the following:

```
String a = "0.11";
Convert.ToSingle(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: You: _make it invariant so both possibilities can be accepted_ No, the `InvariantCulture` uses only `"."` for the `NumberDecimalSeparator`, and only `","` for the `NumberGroupSeparator`. It does not allow "both possibilities". For example, `Convert.ToSingle("23.456,78", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` does not succeed. And `Convert.ToSingle("23456,78", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` produces a value near 2.3 million, not 23 thousand.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thank you for the detailed correction of my answer, would you care to edit it and add the corrective details from your comment?